# Deploying Django restfule service using WAMP and mod_wsgi

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, django-wsgi

I am trying to deploy an API built on Django rest-framework using mod_wsgi and WAMP.
When I created a new Django project using 'django-admin startproject Predictor' and deployed it on WAMP, it was working fine as I can see the default Django window.

Now I created an app in the project using 'python manage.py startapp Predictor'
I built an API which accepts GET call and tested it using 'python manage.py runserver' and it was working fine.
Now I started WAMP service again and try to go to 'localhost:8000' it keeps loading. And as soon as I stop WAMP service it crashes saying Unable to connect. Not sure what's happening. Can someone help what's wrong I am doing? FYI I am on windows and I have created and virtual environment for my Django project. This is how my .conf and wsgi files look like

**wsgi_windows.py**

```
activate_this = 'C:/Users/DELL/Envs/predenv/Scripts/activate_this.py'
# execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
exec(open(activate_this).read(),dict(__file__=activate_this))

import os
import sys
import site

# Add the site-packages of the chosen virtualenv to work with
site.addsitedir('C:/Users/DELL/Envs/predenv/Lib/site-packages')

# Add the app's directory to the PYTHONPATH
sys.path.append('C:/Users/DELL/Envs/predenv')
sys.path.append('C:/Users/DELL/Envs/predenv/Predictor')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'Predictor.settings'
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Predictor.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**httpd.conf**

```
Listen localhost:8000
Listen [::0]:80
ServerName localhost:8000

LoadFile "c:/python376/python37.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/python376/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp37-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "c:/python376"
WSGIPythonPath "C:/Users/DELL/Envs/predenv/Predictor"
```

httpd-vhosts.conf

```
WSGIPythonPath "C:/Users/DELL/Envs/predenv/Predictor"
<VirtualHost *:80>
    WSGIPassAuthorization On
    ErrorLog "logs/predictor.error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/predictor.access.log" combined
    DocumentRoot "C:/Users/DELL/Envs/predenv/Predictor"
    WSGIScriptAlias /  "C:\Users\DELL\Envs\predenv\Predictor\Predictor\wsgi_windows.py"
    <Directory "C:\Users\DELL\Envs\predenv\Predictor\Predictor">
        <Files wsgi_windows.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: The default port for Django's test server is 8000, not 8081.  If you update your configuration to listen on port 8000, will you still get the error?

Comment: @ja408  I revert it back to 8000 port. But the error is the same

Comment: ok, I am not using Windows, so I can't trouble shoot much further.  Sorry.  Did you restart the wamp server?  Could be caching issue?

Comment: @ja408 Yes I did restart the WAMP and accessed it in private/incognito window. Now the error is different and I have updated the question with the same

Comment: In your vhost file change `<VirtualHost *:8081>` to `<VirtualHost *:8000>`, then restart wamp and see if you get a different result

Comment: Made the change. Now the error is 

"Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource."

Comment: Are your file permissions correct on the folder that your project is in, i.e. `C:/C4U/Predictor/` Do you have read / execute rights on that folder and it's subfolders?

Comment: Yes I do have read and write rights to the project folder.

Comment: in your httpd.conf file, search for `onlineoffline tag` under that is the option set `Require local`?  If so, try setting it to `Require all granted`  then restart wamp and see if that solves the issue.

Comment: @ja408 I made the change you asked. With that, I also added updated <Directory "C:\wamp64\www"> to <Directory "C:/C4U/Predictor">. As on 'C:/C4U/Predictor' path my Django Project exists. But now when I access localhost:8000 it's showing me Django project folder and 'localhost:8000/predict' API call still not working

Comment: If you go to http://localhost:8000 does it load a django project?

Comment: @ja408 on localhost:8000 it's showing me my project folder structure. Something like this https://imgur.com/oDeZlug

Comment: That means you don't have a virtual environment or if you do, it's not being loaded with wsgi.  Since I am not very familiar with a Windows setup, I am not sure how to go about troubleshooting that.  On a Mac I create a virtual environment by running `python -m venv .venv` inside the root of the project.  Your VirtualHost will have to point to that of course.

Comment: @ja408 Yes I didn't setup a virtual environment. It might be a dumb question, but do I really need a virtual environment?

Comment: No you don't need one.  It's a standard practice, but if you are dedicating that server to one app, you can use the global Python as opposed to referencing it through a virtual environment.  But if you plan to have more python projects, I would use a virtual environment so your pip installed packages and versions don't conflict from project to project.

Comment: @ja408 This time I am using virtual environment and deployed it. Now the issue is something else. I have posted a different question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61002997/not-able-to-deplot-django-restfule-service-using-wamp-and-mod-wsgi

Comment: Sorry I can't get you to the finish line on this one.  Hopefully someone that is familiar with a windows setup can get you all the way.  I don't know what else it could be.

Comment: @ja408 The issue was it was not able to 'import pandas' in my views.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was it was not able to 'import pandas' in my views.py

To resolve this I have to add this line in my apache 'httpd-vhosts.conf' file

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```